# Using C# and CNTK, how do you create a feed forward neural network?

Tags: c#, cntk

I'm trying to use CNTK to create a basic mlp network. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/using-cntk-with-csharp

However, I'm having issues understanding exactly how I can do this but the examples don't help me much. Could someone help explain me how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I was looking for the answer to the same question.
I hope this helps.
https://bhrnjica.net/2017/11/13/train-iris-data-with-minibatchsource-using-cntk-and-c/

Answer (score 1):

Some C# training examples have just been published at the CNTK repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp